# WireMock.Net leaves the port open after process terminates

Tags: tcp, port, wiremock

I started using WireMock.net in my tests, but occasionally when I run the test I get an exception:

```
Failed to bind to address http://0.0.0.0:9999: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Clearly the fault is in the previous run which didn't close the port. Using TCPView from SysInternals, I see that the process which holds that port is "" and I cannot kill it, nor find the PID in Task Manager nor able to kill it using `taskkill`. **The only solution I found is to restart** or at least to log-off/log-on to Windows. I searched the Web (and StackOverflow) in order to understand how can a process still hold a port even though it's been terminated, but didn't find any useful explanation.

Because it only happens occasionally, and because each time it happens it requires a restart, it makes it a nightmare to debug and investigate. It seems though that it happens when the sending application crashes while sending or receiving a message, but I'm not sure.

I would like to know:

1. If someone knows what's the condition in which the port can be kept open after the process terminates
2. How can this be prevented or mitigated?
3. In case this happens, is there a simpler way to release the port? (maybe there's a service which I can restart?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone who may encounter the same issue:

Seems like killing the client process released the port. However it happened to me only once since I wrote the question, so I couldn't verify it. This answers my 3rd question, but I still cannot find exactly when and why it happens and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestion:

- In the unit-tests, run WireMock.Net on a random port instead of fixed port. Using a fixed port can cause issues when running these unit-tests on a build-server, there is not 100% guarantee that this port will be free on the OS.

For some analysis : see https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/